# How do I remove the hex suffix from DNF cachedir names on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, directory, cache, dnf

DNF uses cachedirs labeled like this:

```
/var/cache/dnf/fedora-d174f3c3f2691dd5
/var/cache/dnf/updates-d28e3be95240972f
```

How do I configure DNF to not add the unique identifier?

With YUM, I symlinked the contained packages directories to a location on a local server. Doing this on my several installs meant I would only need to download an updated package once, yet install it on all of the installs.

I can symlink the DNF packages directories, but every few months, DNF creates a new unique ID, which means I need to go and replace all of the packages directories with symlinks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since `dnf` is written in python, you can look through the sources to find the purpose of this unique identifier. In `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/repo.py`, class `Repo`, method `cachedir()` you can see the id is calculated as a sha256 hash of the url used to retrieve the repository:

```
digest = hashlib.sha256(url.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()[:16]
```

If your `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` has a typical configuration like

```
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
```

then the hash will vary when the `$releasever` release version changes, eg from fedora 22 to 23, which is not very often.  This allows dnf to keep a cache that is specific to a release, so you might not want to keep the same name for the cache.

Comment: Based on your response, I actually tried removing the digest from the pathname concatenation in the python scrypt. It didn't work, which, on the bright side, means I don't need to worry about that change breaking the next update of the DNF repo.py script. I wasn't too worried about the rpms from the different releases going to the same directory: the file names indicate fc22 and fc23. This 23 install still has some 22 RPMs installed.